# Display string method by pressing a button in GUI

Tags: java, button, methods, printing

How would I be able to display this method in a GUI, just by pressing a button in the GUI

```
private String questionFredricton(){
    Object qFredricton = cities.get(1);
    String displayFredricton  = "Where is " + qFredricton + " located?"; 
    String ansFredricton = provinces.get(1);
    return displayFredricton + ansFredricton;  
    }
```

I'm guessing something like this??
nextQuestion is my button

```
private void nextQuestionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        print(questionFredricton());

}
```

I don't want to use use setText() or append() in my button because my strings are being displayed in separate textAreas, already defined in my method.  If I do use setText/appnd, it puts all the strings in one box, which is not what I want.
for example by doing:

```
outputTextQuestion.setText(questionFredricton());//not what I want
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think I fully understand what your asking but you could return a custom object rather then a string in your method. The object would have getters and setters for each string value you want to use. Your `actionPerformed` method then could get the values you need and do whatever with them.

```
public class MyFredriction
 private String display;
 private String answer;

 public MyFredriction(String display, String answer) {
   this.display = display;
   this.answer = answer;
 }
 //TODO public String getDisplay()
 //TODO public String getAnswer()
}
```